# MySQL can't add foreign key although column signatures are the same

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb, errno

I'm creating new database and I want to create a table `Supplier_StockOut`:

```
CREATE TABLE StockOut_Supplier (
  idStockOut_Supplier INT NOT NULL,
  idStockOut INT NOT NULL,
  idSupplier INT NOT NULL,
  idTransactionType INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (idSupplier) REFERENCES Suppliers(idSupplier)
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (idStockOut) REFERENCES StockOuts (idStockOut)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (idTransactionType) REFERENCES TransactionTypes(idTransactionType)
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=innodb DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci;
```

Result:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'stocktest.stockout_supplier' (errno: 150)
```

All tables that those key references are defined properly. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Suppliers (
  idSupplier INT NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=innodb DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci;
```

Even if I leave only the one Foreign Key (for instance to the Suppliers) - result will remain the same.

Same thing happens when I'm trying to create table without foreign keys and do `ALTER TABLE` later to add them. I noticed I can add them without `ON DELETE ON UPDATE` clauses but not with them.

EDIT: There are many InnoDB databases using a lot of foreign keys on this server so I guess it's not server-configuration related problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `StockOut_Supplier` table, columns `idSupplier` and `idTransactionType` are set not to accept `NULL`s but by foreign key declarations you're telling it to set their values to `NULL` on deletion of the primary key.

You might want to set those to `RESTRICT` or `CASCADE` instead.

Comment: Wow. What a mistake. Shame on me ;) Thank for pointing this out.

Comment: @Joe No problem. I myself have made this mistake over and over, that's why I know what to look for :)

Answer (score 0):

ON DELETE SET NULL is the problem because you set NOT NULL on idSupplier
But try running script like this:

```
CREATE TABLE StockOut_Supplier (
  idSupplier INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (idSupplier) REFERENCES Suppliers(idSupplier)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

ALTER TABLE StockOut_Supplier
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (idSupplier) REFERENCES Suppliers(idSupplier)
    ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

Comment: No it was just my mistake and you cannot do NOT NULL and SET NULL on same row. I wrote in question that `ALTER` is not working to anyway ;)